# URL validating process in WebKit

Tags: webkit

I'm developing a Web browser and I need to get information about the process of validating of an url address in webkit, I mean, once a user enter the url address, how the webkit valid it grammatically (for example, if it contains a comma, like ",com", instead the point (like .com)..) and also in the server side, if the url exists or not..
I want to know what methods the webkit uses to do this validation ..
so, if anyone knows a material which responds to this or a website, I would give me addresses or tracks ...
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely this is handled by the KURL class - http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/platform/KURL.cpp -
and the code that might interest you starts in
void KURL::parse(const String& string);